# Can we use Restler on Google App Engine

Tags: php, android, google-app-engine, restler

I want to create a website on Google Cloud (Google App Engine & Restler RESTful API Server) with sub domains:

`http://api.restlerongooglecloud.com` for hybrid app (Android, iOS, Windows) `joomla.restlerongooglecloud.com` for blog and `restlerongooglecloud.com` for main page.

I was wondering if I can create/prepare website to use Restler using GoogleAppEngine SDK and then upload to Google App Engine as a live website pointing to `http://api.restlerongooglecloud.com`.

Restler uses Composer to manage its dependencies so need to keep `composer.phar` in the project folder or ideally in `usr/local/bin`.

My question is after everything is setup as per Restler documention on local machine and tested to work fine, if I upload the project to Google cloud app engine will it work?

References:

[App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/products/app-engine/)

[Restler](http://luracast.com/products/restler)

On Google App Engine Launcher (platform Windows8 ) I get following error when I point to url:

```
hxxp: // localhost:10085/api/public/examples/_001_helloworld/say/hello

{ "error": { "code": 404, "message": "Not Found" }, "debug": { "source": "Routes.php:359 at route stage", "stages": { "success": [ "get" ], "failure": [ "route", "negotiate", "message" ] } } }
```

How to fix this?

app.yaml is as follows:

```
application: restlerongae
version: 1

runtime: php

api_version: 1



handlers:
## api images
- url: /api/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  static_files: api/\1
  upload: api/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  application_readable: true

## api html
- url: /api/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  static_files: api/\1
  upload: api/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  application_readable: true

## api test1
- url: /api/(.*)
  script: api/public/examples/_001_helloworld/index.php
```

Comment: @KrupaPatel, you should be more careful when editing posts. Just adding code format boxes won't make the post better. Take your time when editing, don't do a sloppy job.

Comment: why not just upload it and find out?

Comment: I have tried to upload Restler 3 RC5 but unable to configure `app.yml` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Restler 3 RC5 had some pull requests to make it compatible with google app engine and they are  accepted and then improved upon.

So, Yes Restler should be fine with AppEngine. If you face any issues you can always reach us!

Comment: May I request to post here `app.yml` file for restler to work on GAE.  I am unable to configure `app.yml` correctly to work on google app engine sdk